# get selected option of multi dropdown jquery angular dosn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Hello I'm workig with jquery in angular app, I want to get all selected option of many select list in my component ts file with jquery, what I did :

```js
    $("#selectProp select").each(() => {

      var t = $(this);
      console.log($(this))
      //arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(arr)
```

Here with `this` I want to get the select with selected option from user but in this I get :

```js
0 => jQuery.fn.init(1)   AppComponent
```

Here I get the values declared in export class AppComponent

And Here my Html :

```html
 <div id="selectProp">
              <div *ngFor="let BR of splits; let i = index">
                <label for="pet-select">Morceau {{i + 1}}</label>
                <div>
                  <select id="selectAttribut">
                    <option *ngFor="let prop of lstProp512" [value]="prop.Text">
                      {{prop.Text}}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please make sure that the snippets work (show the problem) when you use them (they're useless otherwise)

Comment: Why not just use a FormGroup and let Angular provide you the selected value(s)?

Comment: I'm not sure `this` works with arrow functions

Comment: I changed to $('#selectProp select').each((index, element) => { I get the select in element but I don't know how to get the selected option in that element select, I try element.add("option:selected").text() but dosn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this it is working :

```js
    $('#selectProp select').each((index, element) => {
      var conceptName = $(element).find(":selected").text();
      console.log(conceptName);
    })
```